# TSC ERRNO 2 WHEN STARTING THE PROJECT

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:42:47 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

42 type PromisifyAllKeys<T> = T extends string ? `${T}Async` : never;
                                                 ~~~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:42:59 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

42 type PromisifyAllKeys<T> = T extends string ? `${T}Async` : never;
                                                             ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:54:17 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

54   [K in keyof T as PromisifyAllKeys<K>]: ExtractAsyncMethod<T[K]>;
                   ~~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:54:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

54   [K in keyof T as PromisifyAllKeys<K>]: ExtractAsyncMethod<T[K]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:54:39 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

54   [K in keyof T as PromisifyAllKeys<K>]: ExtractAsyncMethod<T[K]>;
                                         ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:54:40 - error TS1135: Argument expression expected.

54   [K in keyof T as PromisifyAllKeys<K>]: ExtractAsyncMethod<T[K]>;
                                          ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:54:66 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

54   [K in keyof T as PromisifyAllKeys<K>]: ExtractAsyncMethod<T[K]>;
                                                                    ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:55:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

55 };
   ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:58:17 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

58   [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
                   ~~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:58:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

58   [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
                      ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:58:25 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

58   [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
                           ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:58:50 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

58   [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
                                                    ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:58:51 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

58   [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
                                                     ~

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:59:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

59 };
   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:43 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

73             | ReadonlyArray<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:66 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

73             | ReadonlyArray<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                                    ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:67 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

73             | ReadonlyArray<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                                     ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:74:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

74             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:74:38 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

74             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:74:53 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

74             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:74:61 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

74             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:74:62 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

74             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                                ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:75:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

75             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:75:31 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

75             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:75:39 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

75             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
                                         ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:75:40 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

75             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
                                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:77:5 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

77     );
       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:79:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

79     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:79:31 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

79     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:79:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

79     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:79:46 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

79     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                                                ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:16 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

80     delete(name: string): void;
                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:24 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

80     delete(name: string): void;
                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:25 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

80     delete(name: string): void;
                           ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:31 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

80     delete(name: string): void;
                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:81:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

81     get(name: string): string | null;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:81:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

81     get(name: string): string | null;
                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

82     getAll(name: string): string[];
                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:25 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

82     getAll(name: string): string[];
                           ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:34 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

82     getAll(name: string): string[];
  

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:83:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

83     has(name: string): boolean;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:83:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

83     has(name: string): boolean;
                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:84:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

84     set(name: string, value: string): void;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:84:28 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

84     set(name: string, value: string): void;
                              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:84:37 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

84     set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:84:43 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

84     set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:85:11 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

85     sort(): void;
             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:85:17 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

85     sort(): void;
                   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:87:11 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

87     keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:87:37 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

87     keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:88:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

88     values(): IterableIterator<string>;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:88:39 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

88     values(): IterableIterator<string>;
                                         ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:89:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

89     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:89:38 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

89     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:89:53 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

89     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:89:63 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

89     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:90:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

90     forEach<THIS_ARG = void>(
                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:90:28 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

90     forEach<THIS_ARG = void>(
                              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:91:17 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

91         callback: (this: THIS_ARG, value: string, name: string, searchParams: this) => void,
                   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:91:92 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

91         callback: (this: THIS_ARG, value: string, name: string, searchParams: this) => void,
                                                                                              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:92:17 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

92         thisArg?: THIS_ARG,
                   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:93:5 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

93     ): void;
       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:93:6 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

93     ): void;
        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:93:12 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

93     ): void;
              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:95:34 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

95     readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "URLSearchParams";
                                    ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:96:24 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

96     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:96:48 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

96     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:96:63 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

96     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:96:73 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

96     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                                           ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:97:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

97 }
   ~


Found 70 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! mobility-dashboard-api@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mobility-dashboard-api@1.0.0 tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-14T10_57_45_494Z-debug.log
```

I encountered an issue when executing my project. In my case, when running the project, I received an error with ERRNO 2. I have tried reinstalling Node.js, deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json files, and reinstalling the packages, but it didn't work. I also attempted to downgrade TypeScript, but that didn't resolve the issue either. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Enable skipLibCheck? Why are you using Bluebird?

Comment: this is the project im clone from my company, and when i  npm install then show this error, btw how i enable skipLibCheck ?